# Expo Camera FaceDetector Landmark Points

Tags: react-native, expo

In expo-face-detector I have added detectLandmarks as below in Camera

```
<Camera   
   style={{ flex: 1 }}
   type='front'
   onFacesDetected = {faceDetected}
   FaceDetectorSettings = {{
       mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.accurate,
       detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.all,
       runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.all,
       minDetectionInterval: 5000,
       tracking: false
      }}
  >
```

but data that seems to be print on console.log(faces) within faceDetected function is below only. How to get coordinate of landmraks such as rightEyePosition, leftEyePosition etc as a part of output

```
object {
  "faces": Array [
    Object {
      "bounds": Object {
        "origin": Object {
          "x": 68.6222222222222,
          "y": 431.6488888888889,
        },
        "size": Object {
          "height": 339.62222222222226,
          "width": 220.44444444444446,
        },
      },
      "faceID": -1,
      "rollAngle": 0.12390166521072388,
      "yawAngle": 0.6850103139877319,
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.none,`

```js
const faceDetected = (faces) => {
  console.log(faces)
}
```